# Permutations for possible codes

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

A warehouse tracks inventory using stock codes consisting of a sequence of 5 letters chosen from A B C D E F G H J K followed by a sequence of 4 digits in the range 1 ... 6. How many possible codes are there?

I've got that $$10P5=30240$$ $$6P4=360$$

Not too sure where to go from here?

Comment: Why are you assuming that the digits must be different?

Comment: So would it instead be $$10C5 * 6C4$$?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so you can choose any one of the $10$ digits so you get $10^5$ choices since at each place of a letter you can choose any one of the ten and now the same logic applies for the numbers from $1,2,\ldots 6$ so you get $6^4$ choices for your numbers or digits to be selected. This will cover all possible arrangements including ones where the numbers and digits are all different. So you get, $$10^5 \cdot 6^4$$ choices.